# Как запретить прокрутку контенту, а оверлею разрешить

Tags: javascript, html, css, css3, html5

Есть такая вёрстка https://mihinov.github.io/news/

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

При нажатии на меню, выходит оверлей и тегу `body` задается стиль `overflow: hidden`, который запрещает прокрутку всего `body`

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Я хочу сделать так, чтобы в выезжающем меню было много контента и его можно было скроллить, а задний фон при этом оставался на месте, подскажите, как это можно сделать, не понимаю.
Я пробовал задавать `overflow: hidden` для основного контента, но это не отменяет прокрутку, возможно есть какой-то другой способ для отмены прокрутки?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Нужно фиксированному оверлею `.burger__menu` обнулить все координаты, а также контейнеру, в котором находились элементы, задать `height: auto`, а не 100%

Было:

```css
.burger__menu {
    overflow: auto;
    width: 100%;
    min-height: 150vh;
    background-color: rgba(97, 93, 93, 0.95);
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    transform: translateX(-100%);
    transition: transform .7s ease-in-out;
    z-index: 1;
}

.container {
    max-width: 1300px;
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding: 0 10px;
    height: 100%;
}
```

Стало:

```css
.burger__menu {
    overflow-y: auto;
    width: 100%;
    background-color: rgba(97, 93, 93, 0.95);
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    transform: translateX(-100%);
    transition: transform .7s ease-in-out;
    z-index: 1;
}

.container {
    max-width: 1300px;
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding: 0 10px;
}

.burger__menu .container {
    padding: 10px 10px 60px 10px;
}
```